# 24th Nov 2019.0515 hrs.GMT +1.saw a line of stars moving in a staright line.straight.what could it be?

Tags: universe

While doing our morning navigation watch.. we saw stars moving in line.. it continued for atleast 10 mins.. not a airplane or shooting stars.. Can it be satellites orbiting??

Comment: In addition to the suggested duplicate, you might find this interesting: [Why is one Starlink satellite not following the adjacent one in this image?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40055/12102) *Welcome to Stack Exchange, and happy navigating!